# Prove that for a sequence of people sets $S_1,...,S_d$, $\Delta_i \not = 0$ for all people

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> We have $k$ people $p_1,...,p_k$, and $d$ people sets $S_1,...,S_d$,
>   where the sizes of $S_1,...,S_d$ can vary between $1$ and $k$ (so each
>   $S_1,...,S_d$ is a set of some people from $p_1,...,p_k$).
>
> Define $\Delta_i$ = $\lceil\sum \frac{1}{|S_j|}\rceil: p_i\in S_j$. We
>   say that a sequence of people sets is *fair* iff we can assign one
>   person to each people set such that $\Delta_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ such
>   that $1\le i \le k$ (whenever an assignment is made, $\Delta_i$ is
>   reduced by $1$) **and** $p_i$ is in the set it is assigned to. Prove that any sequence $S_1,...,S_d$ is fair.

As an example, consider $p_1,p_2,p_3$ and sets $S_1=\{p_2,p_3\}$, $S_2=\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$. Then $\Delta_1 = \lceil 1/3\rceil = 1$, $\Delta_2 = \lceil 1/2+1/3\rceil = 1$, $\Delta_3 = \lceil 1/2+1/3\rceil = 1$. That means we can assign $p_1,p_2,p_3$ each to only exactly one set. So, $S_1,S_2$ is fair because we can just assign, for example, $p_2$ to $S_1$ and $p_3$ to $S_2$.

As far as the proof goes, I tried induction:

**Base case:** One people set is always fair. Just assign anyone in the set and we're done.

**IH:** Assume $S_1,...,S_{d-1}$ is fair.

**Induction:** This is where my reasoning breaks down. So we need to show that adding another people set to the **IH** keeps the set fair. If this weren't the case (that adding another set makes the whole sequence *not* fair), then that means everyone in $S_d$ has their $\Delta_i$ equal to $0$ by an assignment of them to $S_1,...,S_{d-1}$. However, I don't know how to show that this is actually impossible (even though the result does make intuitive sense to me).

I've found the problem to be very hard to follow. So if there is anything I need to clarify please let me know. I would appreciate any input you may have, as I don't have much time to complete the problem. Thank you!

Comment: The same question was asked in a clearer form [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978947/give-an-algorithm-that-computes-a-fair-driving-schedule-for-all-people-in-a-carp) (and in that form by you or someone with the same name in [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32068/prove-that-there-always-exists-a-fair-driving-schedule)).

Answer (score 3):

Have you learned about network flow?

If so, the solution should be obvious once you set up the graph.

You can representing this problem with a bipartite graph. One part is the $p_i$ nodes and the other part is the $S_j$ sets. Draw an arc from $p_i$ to $S_j$ if $p_i \in S_j$.  Add a source with an arc to each $p_i$ with capacity $\Delta_i$. Then give each $(p_i, S_j)$ arc capacity 1, and add a sink node with an arc from each $S_j$ with capacity 1.

Comment: The network flow graph can only be used as a check for whether the sequence is fair, but it is not sufficient to prove that any sequence is fair. Do you have any suggestions for how the graph may *prove* any sequence is always fair?

Comment: @Jenn: Construct a flow $f$ with $|f|=d$. Start with $f_{p_i,S_j}=\frac1{|S_j|}$ and $f_{S_j,\text{sink}}=1$. I leave you to work out the $f_{\text{source},p_i}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm sorry, I'm a little confused with the notation. Do you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: Wouldn't $f_{source,p_i} = \Delta_i$? Though I don't see how this proves a fair sequence will always exist.

Comment: Do you know the network flow integrality theorem?